# Free cloud storage required

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am a Mtech student and currently doing my project in cloud environment. I am looking for a free cloud storage with small memory to upload and access text files on to cloud. Is there any cloud storage which can help in my requirements. 
Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: Why don't you use Google Drive? or Dropbox?

Comment: I want more like google cloud or amazon cloud.. is there any alternative

Comment: If your total storage requirements are very small, you can probably afford Google Cloud Storage. Storing a gigabyte over a month will cost you about 8 cents, and downloading that gigabyte every single day will cost you about 12 cents per day. That's about $4 for the whole month. Or you can just use Google Drive for free. It also has an API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon S3 going to be one of the best solution, But you are talking about free. I would suggest you to go for dropbox it's free upto some extent. I already integrated with my rails application, they are providing API and Secret Key for app configuration.

Have a look to below link

[12 free cloud storage options](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/092512-free-cloud-262764.html)

[Five Best Cloud Storage Providers](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-cloud-storage-providers-614393607)

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities: Amazon S3, Dropbox, GoogleDrive..

Be aware of network latency if your app is deployed outside the same physical infrastructure.

You can find a complete application example working on CloudBees + Amazon S3 ([here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart))

However, you can get a similar approach through the runtime and file system storage you want.